# Kак решить вопрос,использую "SearchBar" и "JSON" в Xamarin,получить данную ошибку

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Данная ошибка

```
 System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: source'
```

GetJSON

```
       private async void GetJSON()
        {

            //Check network status   
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
                {

                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("");
                string contactsJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

             //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list  
            var ObjContactList = (Contact[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact[]>(contactsJson);
            var descListOb = ObjContactList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Recovered);
            listviewConacts.ItemsSource = descListOb;


        }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("JSONParsing", "No network is available.", "sex");
            }
            //Hide loader after server response    
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

CountrySearchBar_TextChanged

```
        public List<Contact> Items { get; set; }
        private void CountrySearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        var keyword = CountrySearchBar.Text;

        IEnumerable<Contact> sugggestions = Items.Where(c => 
        c.CombinedKey.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));  

        listviewConacts.ItemsSource = sugggestions;
    }
```

JsonModel

```
public  class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty("provinceState")]
    public string ProvinceState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryRegion")]
    public string CountryRegion { get; set; }
 }


 }
```

Comment: Как правило данная ошибка говорит о том что коллекция к которой вы обращаетесь не иницализировна. В какой именно строчке когда этот эксепшн возникает?

Comment: CountrySearchBar_TextChanged

Comment: IEnumerable<Contact> sugggestions = Items.Where(c => 
        c.CombinedKey.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));

Comment: перед обращением к элементу `Items` проверьте что он `!= null`

Comment: как сделать?не могу

Comment: Вы меня извините но если Вы не знаете как использовать условный оператор,  то я рекомендую Вам еще раз пройти курс c# с первой главы.

Comment: Я так написал,и не хочет:
            if (Items!= null) { 
                var sugggestions = Items.Where(c => c.CombinedKey.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
                listviewConacts.ItemsSource = sugggestions;
            }

Comment: Ок, тогда проверьте ещё что бы переменная `c` внутри выражения `where` так же была инициализирована, например так Items.Where(c => c != null && остальное ваше условие)

Comment: listviewConacts.BeginRefresh();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                
                    listviewConacts.ItemsSource = Items;
            }
            else {
                if (Items != null) { 
                    listviewConacts.ItemsSource = Items.Where(c => c != null && c.CombinedKey.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
                }
                
            }
           listviewConacts.EndRefresh();
        }

Comment: не хочет:( .....

Comment: А вы уверены что именно в этом месте эксепшен происходит? Вы запускаете отладку и у вас программа падает прям на этой коллекции? Если да то не выключая отладку наведите курсор на переменные и посмотрите какая из них не инициализирована, к примеру элемент коллекции `с` точно имеет проинициализированное поле CombinedKey? , `e` тоже проверьте что б там все было и не было null